# img doesn't conform to the grid row height

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I can't seem to get the `img` to conform to the `max-height` of the *grid row* (`45px`).

I would also love to know if there is a cleaner way to have the `img` conform to the *height* of the list elements without setting a *row height*.

Thank you!

```css
.menu ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: 45px;
}

.menu a {
  background: #74d3ae;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.menu img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  grid-column: 1 / span 1;
  grid-row: 1 / span 1;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="menu">
    <ul id="menu-list">
      <li>
        <a href=""><img class="logopic" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" alt="logo"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Beers</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Wines</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Desserts</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Reservations</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: *grid row height*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can omit its *grandparent* `li`:

```css
.menu ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: 45px;
}

.menu a {
  background: #74d3ae;
  display: block; /* necessary */
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.menu img {
  width: 100%; /* optional */
  height: 100%; /* necessary */
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="menu">
    <ul id="menu-list">
      <a href=""><img class="logopic" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" alt="logo"></a>
      <li>
        <a href="">Beers</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Wines</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Desserts</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Reservations</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```